# How get an axis unsqueezed on a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, axes

For plotting a heatmap I did:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, dpi=dpi)
im0 = ax.imshow(data, cmap='Wistia')
```

Due to the dimensionality of data with (300K, 20) resulting Y-axis was squeezed.
[image]

Maybe squeezing of Y-axis happened because of :

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im0, cax=cax)
```

How can I get heatmap more look like (with full Y-range [0, 20]):

[image]

Comment: Pass aspect=‘auto’ to imshow